# How to only output [a-z;A-Z;0-9;|] chars with ksh?

Tags: ksh, openbsd

How can I "whitelist"/output only the (ENglish) a-z;A-Z;0-9;| chars and space in ksh/OpenBSD 5.3?

```
$ echo 'ASDF"`date`ew � kd A | A'
ASDF"`date`ew � kd A | A
$ echo 'ASDF"`date`ew � kd A | A' | MAGIC
ASDFdateew  kd A | A
```

So **Q:** MAGIC is needed :)

UPDATE:

```
echo 'a|d' | LC_ALL=EN tr -dc '[:alnum:][:space:]|'
a|d
```

This works in console, but If I put it in a CGI script then it outputs this:

```
a7Cd
```

Why?

Comment: Your CGI script sctually outputs `a%7Cd`. Maybe you should post a separate question if you need help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 'áé{D`AS' | LC_ALL=C tr -cd '[:alnum:]|'
```

(note that it will also remove the newline character appended by `echo`).

`LC_ALL` fixes the *locale* which determines what characters are and which of them are considered letters or numbers. In the C locales, characters are single-bytes and `alnums` are the ASCII characters A to Z, a to z and 0 to 9.

Comment: what is LC_ALL? + whoops, great.. "|" will be needed too..